# Looking for classic intro to intermediate algebra books, similar to AOPS

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I am looking for a classic intro to intermediate or intermediate algebra book OTHER than gelfand’s. I own gelfand algebra and while it’s great, it doesn’t go into logarithms and it is a little short. Preferably a book or books similar to AOPS Algebra - Intermediate Algebra books. I like AOPS books but I’ve used a few and I prefer the style of non US texts.

*Recommendations for a classic intro to intermediate algebra book, preferably non American. Rigorous is good too*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "intermediate algebra" (the term has a specific meaning in U.S. colleges, especially in community colleges, and there are very many texts with that phrase as their title), but this usage that I am familiar with is for books designed for remedial work, which is far removed from what AOPS is designed for. So I'll assume you mean advanced school level algebra. For advanced school level algebra, there are many older freely available texts that might be of interest to you, such as the following.

William Steadman Aldis -- [**A Text Book of Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/textbookofalgebr00aldirich)

George Chrystal -- **Algebra. An Elementary Text-Book** ([Part I](https://archive.org/details/algebraelementar01chryuoft) and [Part II](https://archive.org/details/cu31924001533110))

George Chrystal -- [**Introduction to Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoal00chry)

Henry Burchard Fine -- [**A College Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/acollegealgebra01finegoog)

Hall and Knight -- [**Higher Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/higheralgebraseq00hall)

Charles Smith -- [**A Treatise on Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonalge00smitgoog)

Isaac Todhunter -- [**Algebra for the use of Schools and Colleges**](https://archive.org/details/algebraforuseofc00todhuoft)

Webster Wells -- [**Advanced Course in Algebra**](https://archive.org/details/advancedcoursei00wellgoog)

Wilczynski and Slaught -- [**College Algebra with Applications**](https://archive.org/details/collegealgebrawi00wilc)

The above happen to be on my bookshelves (obtained at various times and in various used bookstores during the past several decades) and simply by googling their titles/authors along with *archive.org*, I was able to find freely available digitized copies of all of them.

See also [this list of online books](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/browse?type=lcsubc&key=Algebra).